# Check if user already logged in okta on startup of website or application. so that we don't need to login again

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, single-sign-on, identityserver4, okta

I have added one more button apart from regular login button, the button is sing in with okta. when clicked it challange and redirect to okta username and password after that my code execute and login. But i want to do something like if i am already login in okta and when i open my site it should directly log me in without clicking sing in with okta button. Is that possible ?

Comment: What type of application is this? You can check if a user is already logged into Okta from your app (3rd party cookie dependent) by making a request to the [sessions endpoint](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/sessions/#get-current-session) and use the response from that to determine whether to show the login form or to send the user straight to the application

Comment: @Andrea it is .net core application . 
 I checked that i can do my login code on login GET method whatever i have done on login POST method, in that case it will check for login without login button click . 
 
 But i want to know that is there any way that if my url is triggerd it check if i have session with okta site already then use that login in my application without making challange again it just return me http.user.authenticated true by okta site session?